# tabindex not maintained for overlay div's focussable elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, accessibility

I have one div with product image. When user comes to this div by pressing tab or mouse then I am showing one overlay div along with some links and buttons.

Problem: when overlay window is open with some links/button then tabindex is not maintained for overlay's button elements.

So I want to switch the focus to overlay focusable elements when overlay window is open. When tabindex reach to last element then it should move to another focusable element outside the overlay window.

HTML Code

```
<h2><a href="">tab 1</a></h2>
<h2><a href="">tab 2</a></h2>

<div class="container">
 <a href=""><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%"></a>
  <div class="middle-overlay" style="display: none;">
    <button>Tab 3</button>
    <button>Tab 4</button>

  </div>

</div>
 <h2><a href="">tab 5</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="">tab 6</a></h2>

 $('.container').on('mouseover focusin', function() {
            $('.middle').show();
        })

        $('.container').on('mouseout focusout', function() {
            $('.middle').hide();
        })
```

My JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnz7Levn/13/

Comment: Hi I don't understand at all what is your purpose. But I think you miss $("#elementID").focus(); functionality. What focus the element you specify in the moment (of the function) you specify.

Comment: I have already tried by focusing the element before or after showing the overlay div. It's not working. I have updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It won't focus in the items inside the container because you are using display:none. Instead of hiding the elements using display none you can use sr-only class and just add and remove that class on focus in and out. Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2><a href="" tabindex="0">tab 1</a></h2>
<h2><a href="">tab 2</a></h2>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%" tabindex="0">
<div class="middle sr-only">
    <button class="first">Tab 3</button>
    <button>Tab 4</button>
</div>
</div>
<h2><a href="">tab 5</a></h2>
<h2><a href="">tab 6</a></h2>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.container').on('mouseover focusin', function() {
  $('.middle').removeClass('sr-only');
})
$('.container').on('mouseout focusout', function() {
  $('.middle').addClass('sr-only');
})
```